# What are free natural AI voices to use for commercial purposes?

Tags: speech-synthesis

I'm wondering which AI voice is both completely free for commercial use and offers the best quality in terms of sounding natural, for use in my YouTube videos?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know any free source, but I used HitPaw Voice Changer, works well for me.

Answer (score 0):

[Bark](https://github.com/suno-ai/bark) is an open-source text-to-audio transformer based language model.

It can be installed as a Python module or integrated into Blender for a more GUI based approach through [Pallaidium addon](https://github.com/tin2tin/Pallaidium).

There is also [Bark-GUI](https://github.com/C0untFloyd/bark-gui) for a more user friendly experience.

It is not a direct text-to-speech tool, it can deviate somewhat from the prompts, but can talk in different languages and even output music.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the information, but I am looking for something lightwheight and fast like online TTS websites that offer natural AI voices. Bark is computational heavy and I am not sure if it's 100% free for commercial use?

Comment: For commercial use you apparently need a payed registered account on the Suno website according to https://suno-ai.notion.site/FAQs-b72601b96de44e5cacd2cd6baa985448#f0f1441180484d6094206e84e334ba36 . That is for the music at least, could not find info about speech generated offline

Comment: @freeman neither "lightweight" nor "fast" appear in your question. Regardless, you can't have lightweight, fast and natural/accurate... That's contradictory.

Comment: But when I search for free TTS, Google brings a lot of websites that really work like real-time, some with very broad and naturlat voices to choose. The problem is that they all have limitations like number of usage per day, max character, non commercial use, etc. But most of them ate really fast and high quality. I ws thinking maybe there is an offline/open source version of them as well

Comment: The fact that they work "real time" doesn't necessarily mean they are lightweight, just that there is enough processing power behind them to afford a timely response. There almost certainly is an unknown amount of infrastructure behind each model, providing processing power to make them appear fast enough to any unaware visitors